# How to get around stateful filters when saving and loading user filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a list of records and I limit the number of records displayed by selecting a number from a dropdown. When the user changes the dropdown the filter works fine.

```
  $scope.recordNumbers = [
        "10", "50", "100", "500", "1000", "10000"
    ];

    $scope.filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber = "10"

<div data-ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber track by item.Id">
{{item.Id}}
</div>
```

However the user has the ability to save and load filters. When I load a filter and change the  $scope.filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber in the controller the dropdown value changes but the filter on the records is not executed.

I have seen some article that point to creating stateful filters to solve this, but they are not recommended due to performance issues. Are there any other workarounds? Maybe triggering the onchanged event of the dropdown from the controller, but Im not sure how I would do that without user interaction on the dropdown.

Comment: how are you loading filters?

Comment: A http call is made, when a response is received $scope.filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber is set to that value. That all works fine, it is that the records aren't filtered when setting $scope.filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber in the controller

Comment: you should post that code, the variables can be overwriting, or are not set correctly in async, etc.

Comment: The variables are being set correctly. $scope.recordNumbers is also shown as a dropdown elsewhere in the page. with $scope.filterGroup.selectedRecordNumber as the model. The selected item of the dropdown changes when the filter is loaded, but the records themselves aren't filtered. This is because by default filters only execute when their inputs have changed. I am looking for a workaround